# How do I remove an object from an array of objects. in knockoutJS. Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

How do I remove an object from an array of objects in Knockoutjs.
I am new to knockoutjs and any help will be appreciated.

[A link to Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/idacoder/9p60g8mh/5/#&togetherjs=pEGhHqm1pV)

Line 24 in the HTML code on jsfiddle is the click binding to delete.
Line 67 in the javascript code on js fiddle is where the function to remove an object from the array is made.
I tried to use indexOf and splice Array functions on line 68 and 69 and it worked to remove but the DOM was not being updated.
Please take a look at the function  removeProduct: function (product)

Html

```
<div>List of Product (<span data-bind="text: products().length"></span>) 
</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li><span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">Select</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div>List of Group Ideas</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: GroupIdeas">
    <li data-bind="text:name">
        <input type="button" value="Removethis" />
        <input type="button" value="vote" />
    </li>

</ul>
<div>List of Group members</div>
</body>

 Javascript



$(function () {
var viewModel = {
    productPrice: ko.observable(89),
    productQty: ko.observable(2),

    products: ko.observable([
        { name: "shoe", price: "788", id: 1 },
        { name: "blouse", price: "50", id: 2 },
        { name: "dress", price: "16", id: 3 },
        { name: "lipstick", price: "88", id: 4 },
        { name: "earring", price: "4", id: 5 },
        { name: "bra", price: "96", id: 6 },
        { name: "lingeringe", price: "48", id: 7 },
        { name: "neclace", price: "36", id: 8 },
    ]),
    GroupIdeas: ko.observable([
        { name: "shoe", price: "788", prodId: 1, selectedby: "Akuba", memId: 
1, votes: 3 },
        { name: "lingeringe", price: "48", prodId: 7, selectedby: "Isaac", 
memId: 2, votes: 6 },
    ]),
    GroupMember: ko.observable([
        { name: "Akuba", relation: "friend", id: 1 },
        { name: "Isaac", relation: "Husband", id: 2 },
        { name: "Ira", relation: "Sister", id: 3 },
        { name: "Davida", relation: "Mum", id: 4 }
    ]),
    partyPerson: ko.observable("Ida"),
    partyOrganiser: ko.observable("Royce"),
    //addProduct = function () { /* ... leave unchanged ... */ }
    removeProduct: function (product) {
        /*var indexArr = viewModel.products().indexOf(product);
        viewModel.products().splice(indexArr, 1)
        */

        viewModel.products().remove(product)
        console.log(product);
    }
};

  viewModel.totalAmt = ko.computed(function () {
      return this.productPrice() * this.productQty();
   }, viewModel);


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
//ko.applyBindings(giftModel);
})**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rjvh6tc/).

1. You need to make `products` an observable array to take advantage of the `remove` function.
2. You need to make a reference to the viewmodel before you can refer to `products`, so your `removeProduct` function has to be written after the viewmodel initialisation. Similar to how you have written `totalAmt`.

   ```
   viewModel.removeProduct = function (product) {
        viewModel.products.remove(function(item){
            return item.id === product.id;
        });
   }
   ```